# Why is Bee Honey Kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, shemot-exodus, non-kosher-species, honey

Honey is formed when a bee mixes enzymes in its own body with nectar from flowers to form honey. Since honey is thus a byproduct of a non-kosher animal, how could it be Kosher while for example, camel milk is not.

I would've thought the reason for this is that in many places such as Shemot 13:5 it says, "...to give you a land flowing with milk and honey..." Hashem wouldn't tell us about the abundance of honey if we couldn't eat it! So, we must be able to eat it. However, Rashi comments on that very passuk saying that the honey in this verse is reffering to date and fig honey, and not bee honey. 
So, what then is the reason we could eat bee honey.

Comment: An excellent question to which I don’t have the answer to!